# Dropbox API with PHP get content of file in Dropbox

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I have a WebApp that stores a backup in the cloud of the user.
I use the third party libary: http://fabi.me/en/php-projects/dropphp-dropbox-api-client/

Login works. But im stuck at the point where I can download it.

The following code downloads the file on the cloud and writes it to a file.

```
$dropbox->DownloadFile( $file, $test_file )
```

But I need the content of the file only in a string and not as file.
The data shouldn't be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, you can't.
However, the `DownloadFile` method is quite simple:
https://github.com/f4bsch/DropPHP/blob/master/DropboxClient.php#L261

My suggestion is to override this method by creating your own, `CustomDropboxClient` by extending the used `DropboxClient` library, then rewrite the file handling logic. It's using the curl library. By setting the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option, you can retrieve the data without writing it to a file.

This should give you enough hints to start this project. If you need anything, just comment.

Comment: Thanks. I did it. The DropboxClient class of the lib got the method execCurlAndClose who is called in the download method. This method returns the content of the file.